How to get Stellarium for Mojave?
What's the newest version of Stellarium that will run on macOS 10.14 Mojave?
And where can it be downloaded?
I can't find system requirements for older versions anywhere on stellarium.org or GitHub.
Thanks.

You probably want to upgrade your OS. OSX 10.14 Mojave is not supported any longer since 2019, and the list of known security issues is lengthy, thus official support has been dropped by Stellarium.
If upgrading your system to a supported version of your OS is not an option, you are stuck with either old versions of the software or have to compile it yourself - an endeavour which gets also increasingly complicated when a system reached end-of-life as also built-time dependencies then often are not available anymore in the needed versions.
Stellarium offers the download of old versions from their archives. 0.19.2 seems to be the latest available there, indicated to work for OSX 10.12+.
There is also stellarium-web for the browser.

There's also Stellarium Web which runs in a web browser

Thanks @AaronF. I added that piece of information
